# Django does not call the function and does not output information from the database

Tags: html, django, django-models

I started learning django recently and am writing a website for a tutor. I need to add output to topics that are entered into the database through the admin panel. But he doesn't take them out. Although the profile data is displayed perfectly.
views.py

```
class TopicListView(ListView):
    model = Topic
    template_name = 'video/video.html'
    context_object_name = 'top'


def video(request):
    top = Topic.objects.all()
    context = {'top': top}
    return render(request, 'video/video.html', context)
```

video.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="icon" href="../static/images/favicon.jpg" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../static/images/favicon.jpg" type="image/x-icon">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Материалы</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'profiles/css/style.css' %}" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <div class="top">
              <a href="/">Главная</a>
              <a class="active" href="video">Материалы</a>
              <a href="question">Тесты</a>
              <a href="accounts/logout"> Выйти</a>
            </div>
            {% for post in top %}
            <div>
            <h3>{{ post.name_topic }}</h3>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}

        {% else %}
            <p>Ввойдите в профиль, чтобы увидеть эту страницу</p>
            <div class="button">
                <a href="accounts/login">Log in</a>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.profiles),
    url(r'^video/$', views.video, name='topic'),
    path('question', views.question),

]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z68VL.png)

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: i didn't have any error, I want to display information taken from the database on the website, but for some reason it does not display it. I read on 1 forum to add "print('wow')" to one of the functions, and if it does not work, then the function is not called. So I want to understand for what reason it may not be called if everything is specified

Comment: Add urls.py please.

Comment: i edit my question and added urls.py

Comment: Are you logged in?

Comment: if it means am I logged into django admin, then yes

Comment: Please share the screenshot of what does actually renders for you. Also a question, o you have any Topics created in your DB?

Comment: Yes, i added any topics on db, and i check this in app 'sqlitestudio' and topics are there